# Why is $E(sin(B_{t-s})) = 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I am wondering why for a Brownian Motion $B_t$ and where $s < t$:

$$
E(sin(B_{t-s})) = 0
$$
?

I can't understand why, can anyone see?

Answer (score 3):

$\sin$ is an odd, bounded, function.  If the distribution of $X$ is symmetric about zero, then $E[\sin(X)]=0$.

Comment: What is the CPV sense and why do you think the assertion E(sin(X))=0 has to be qualified?

Comment: @Did CPV usually stands for the Cauchy principal value, but I do not understand why we need it here since I think $E[\sin X]$ exists since it is bounded by one.

Comment: In general, there are odd functions $g(X)$ for which the convergence of the integral for $E[g(X)]$ might be in question,  For example, it's easy to construct a probability distribution symmetric about 0 such that $E[X^{3}]$ converges only in the Cauchy principal value sense.  As user148692 points out, $| \sin(x) | \leq 1$, so this particular expected value will converge without having to consider the CPV.   That's what I get for answering questions late at night...

Comment: @user148692 My point, indeed.